# Vertically stretch "/" operator when second (but not first) operand is tall

Tags: math-mode

I have code similar to this:

```
\[
x / \sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}
\]
```

I.e. the first part (`x`) is normal height while the second part is tall.  How do I get the `/` to be stretched vertically to match the second part?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on the spacing surrounding the symbol, you could use one of the `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg`, or `\Bigg` commands or their friends for relation symbols `\bigm`, `\Bigm`, `\biggm`, or `\Biggm`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
x \Biggm/ \sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}
\]

\[
x \Bigm/ \sqrt{a/b}
\]

\[
x \Bigg/ \sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}
\]

\[
x \Big/ \sqrt{a/b}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like this that automatically re sizes the slant and handles different sizes on both sides of the slant:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\nfrac}[2]{#1\left/\vphantom{#1}#2\right.}
\begin{document}


\[
\nfrac{x}{\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}}
\]

\[
\nfrac{\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}}{x}
\]

\[
\nfrac{x}{\sqrt{a/b}}
\]

\[
\nfrac{\sqrt{a/b}}{x}
\]

\end{document}
```

The `\phantom` handles the case where the numerator is taller than the denominator.