# How to make brackets larger?

Tags: brackets

How can the first `{` and last `}` in the following be made larger?

```
  $A =\left \{a \notin\{1, 2\}, \ b\notin \{4,5\}\right\}$.
```

Comment: `\big` or similar- have a look at the `Not so short guide to LaTeX`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are several ways to increase the height of the braces:

1. Use a `\vphantom{}` inside the `\left\{` and `\right\}` so that the content appears to have greater height causing the size of the braces to increase:

   ```
   $B =\left\{ \vphantom{y^2} a \notin \{1, 2\} \right\}$
   ```
2. Specify a fixed size of the brace (as **cmhughes** sugested):

   ```
   $C =\big\{ \vphantom{y^2} a \notin \{1, 2\} \big\}$
   ```
3. Or use automatic growth for nested parenthesis as per [automatic size adjustment for nested parentheses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36039/automatic-size-adjustment-for-nested-parentheses):

   ```
   \setlength\delimitershortfall{-2pt}
   $D =\left\{ a \notin \{1, 2\}  \right\}$
   ```

---

### References:

**Fixed Size:**

- [Vertically stretch "/" operator when second (but not first) operand is tall](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21386/vertically-stretch-operator-when-second-but-not-first-operand-is-tall/)

**Automatic Re-size:**

- [automatic size adjustment for nested parentheses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36039/automatic-size-adjustment-for-nested-parentheses)
- ["(" or "\left(" parentheses?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12773/or-left-parentheses)
- [How to adjust brace size for nested braces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74055/how-to-adjust-brace-size-for-nested-braces)

---

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$A =\left\{ \{1, 2\} \right\}$,
$B =\left\{ \vphantom{y^2} \{1, 2\} \right\}$,
$C =\big\{ \{1, 2\} \big\}$,
\setlength\delimitershortfall{-2pt}
$D =\left\{ \{1, 2\}  \right\}$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\rule{0pt}{<height>}` could be considered as a way to manually control de the height of the braces, right? Like `$A =\left\{ \rule{0pt}{9pt} \{1, 2\} \right\}$`,