# Nested \left and \right) make \vphantom have non-zero width

Tags: brackets, width, height, phantom

I have many nested `\left(` and `\right)` parentheses in my document and I'm trying to find a flexible way to make outer pairs larger.

Unfortunately, I cannot use `\delimitershortfall` recommended [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83286/how-to-make-brackets-larger). That made me try `\vphantom`.

Most of the time, `\vphantom` has zero width but when `\left(` and `\right)` are nested, it looks like `\vphantom`'s width becomes non-zero:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\(  \left( \vphantom{\Big|} \left( x \right)  \right)  \) 

\(  \left(  \left( x \right) \vphantom{\Big|} \right)  \)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way around it?

I tried to add `\hspace{-0.17em}` in order to compensate for the non-zero width of `\vphantom` above but it's probably  not a good solution because `\vphantom`'s behaviour appears to be inconsistent. For example, if you replace the inner pair with normal parentheses the problem disappears:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\(  \left( \vphantom{\Big|} ( x )  \right)  \) 

\(  \left(  ( x ) \vphantom{\Big|} \right)  \)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Max already provided a nice answer below. I just want to add that Knuth himself encourages `\big` (and friends) over `\left...\right` in the TeXbook.

Comment: @RuixiZhang the correct form in latex is `\bigl` and `\bigr`. Otherwise you could mess up spacing. (example, `\big( - A \big)` makes latex think you are substracting A from the left paren)

Comment: Many math characters vary their spacing depending on what is next to therm.  It helps to throw in an occasional \null.

Comment: @MaxXiong Well, I said “`\big` (and friends)”…

Answer (score 2):

The extra space is caused by the interaction between the `\vphantom` and `\left(`. TeX's spacing rules will add a space between them. The same problem occurs even just putting a regular variable before `\left(`. If you want to remove the space, do `\!` after `\vphantom`.

Better yet, if you want a global solution, use the `mleftright` package.

As a side-note, for the example you gave, a better way of achieving the result would be `\bigl( ( x ) \bigr)`. `\left` and `\right` are often just too big so I don't like using them unless I have to.